# Is there a way in Python to print an element nested in a div separately from the other data in that div?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm scraping data from this site, and I want to print the data in the `<span>` tag separately and the id attribute. Is that possible here? My goal would be to print "Rescheduled from September 20," "6:30 PM," and "$20" separately.

```
<div id="calendar_info_support">
      <a href="http://www.facebook.com/events/" target="_blank">Rescheduled from September 20</a><br>
      <br>
      <br>
      <br>
      <span class="calendar_info_doors_cover">
      6:30:PM
      <br>
      <a href="http://www.showclix.com/event/" target="_blank">$20 advance SC</a>
      </span>
</div>
```

I'm super new to this so my tool belt is pretty limited. I tried searching, but I couldn't find anything that matched this issue. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

One solution might be using `.get_text()` with unique `separator=` parameter and then split along this separator:

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html_doc = '''\
<div id="calendar_info_support">
      <a href="http://www.facebook.com/events/" target="_blank">Rescheduled from September 20</a><br>
      <br>
      <br>
      <br>
      <span class="calendar_info_doors_cover">
      6:30:PM
      <br>
      <a href="http://www.showclix.com/event/" target="_blank">$20 advance SC</a>
      </span>
</div>'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(html_doc, 'html.parser')

tag = soup.find(id='calendar_info_support')
print(tag.get_text(strip=True, separator='|').split('|'))
```

Prints:

```
['Rescheduled from September 20', '6:30:PM', '$20 advance SC']
```